# Previewing images using Django

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-forms

I have a html,css and js app that I ported to Django and I want to preview an image before upload. A dropdown form allows users to select an option that will then display the image onto the screen before upload. I did this through javascript by setting `img src = ""`  to empty and then when the user selected an option from the dropdown menu, javascript set the img src path i.e if user selected car from menu then js would set `img src=images/car.png` and display it.

```
function displayImage(imgValue){
  if (imgValue == 'car') {
    previewImage.setAttribute("src", "images/car.png");
    previewDefaultText.style.display = "none";
    previewImage.style.display = "block";
  } else if (imgValue == 'location') {
    previewImage.setAttribute("src", "images/newyork.jpg");
    previewDefaultText.style.display = "none";
    previewImage.style.display = "block";
    ....
    ....
}
```

The issue is that the JS isn't setting the path of the `img src` in Django. Can I do this through JS or will it require to rewrite in a more Django/pythonic way? Note: w/o the use of ajax.

Answer (score 0):

```
previewImage.setAttribute('src', "{% static 'images/car.png' %}")
```

I believe this will solve your problem.

Comment: Hey so its now giving me a response: `http://127.0.0.1.com:8000/%7B%%20static%20'images/car.png'%20%%7D` . How can I strip out the encoding in the URL ?

Comment: {% load staticfiles %} add this in your head element

Comment: And be sure you have a static folder registered in your settings. And car.png exist in a folder called images inside the static folder.

Comment: Yeah I had that. It's still returning a encoded url. On the HTML my `img src = " "` is set to empty. I've tried amending it to `img src="{% static 'images/ %}` , `img src="{% static %}` and so on with no luck

Comment: These two you tried are both wrong. Something else too is wrong. Check your syntax thoroughly. Django tends to encode raw html when it's not qouted properly.